# Django Rest Serializer returns empty

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm following this tutorial ([Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)) and I'm facing a problem when I try to use serializers. It returns a empty result, instead the 49086 records that it should to return. My query it's ok because when I try to show the data without serializers it's shows these data. Please, what I'm doing wrong?

**models.py**

```
# coding=utf-8

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class Workers(models.Model):
    chapa = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    emp_cod = models.IntegerField(primary_key=False)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'WORKERS'
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Workers


class WorkersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Workers
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
...
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def get_all_workers(request):
    data = Workers.objects.using('rh').all().order_by('emp_cod')
    print(data.count()) # Returns 49086
    serializer = WorkersSerializer(data)
    print(serializer.data) # Returns {}
    json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
    return Response(json) # Returns Django Rest standard page with "{}" data
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `many=True` serializer's argument to serialize multiple objects. Also you can pass `serializer.data` directly as `Response` argument:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def get_all_workers(request):
    data = Workers.objects.using('rh').all().order_by('emp_cod')
    serializer = WorkersSerializer(data, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Since your view return so many objects at once, I suggest you to add [pagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/):

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def get_all_workers(request):
    data = Workers.objects.using('rh').all().order_by('emp_cod')
    paginator = PageNumberPagination()
    paginator.page_size = 10
    result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(data, request)
    serializer = WorkersSerializer(result_page, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @neverwalkaloner! It works like a charm! And thank you also for the suggestions. It was very helpful !

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I needed to add many=True on my serializer even if the data I am trying to get is only 1